# Não consigo fazer um select em um banco de dados usando PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Oi pessoal não estou conseguindo fazer um select em meu banco de dados PHP.
Já tentei implementar várias soluções, porém ele sempre retorna 0 results, sendo que tenho dados no meu BD.

Estou usando arquivos externos para conexão ao banco e eles estão funcionando.

E o conteúdo dos spans sempre ficam vazios.

```
<?php $idUser = $_SESSION["user_id"];

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         $result =  mysqli_query("SELECT idMessage, name, telefone, mensagem FROM Messages where Messages.idUser =  '$idUser' ");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
            $id  = $row["idMessage"];
            $name = $row["name"];
            $mensagem = $row["mensagem"];
          endwhile;
       } else {
            echo "0 results";
          }
  ?>

      <span><?php  echo $id ?></span>
      <span><?php  echo $name ?></span>
      <span><?php  echo $mensagem ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o **$result** eu acredito que deve estar antes do **if** e não depois. ficando assim:

```
$result =  mysqli_query("SELECT idMessage, name, telefone, mensagem FROM Messages where Messages.idUser =  '$idUser' ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         ...
         ...
```